# App to remember open app/file & browser window and their placement

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is the an app or utility for the Mac (Mavericks - in particular) that will allow me to save everything I have open (apps w/files, various browser windows & tabs) so that they can be reopened later?

I do a lot of research for various projects. Many times I can't complete the research in one sitting and have to try to remember what apps and more importantly what search rabbit trail I had gone down. It would be so much easier if I could take a "snapshot" of what is open, where it is at, save it as a profile / task group / desktop config (saving their size and location on screen) - call it what you want, then reopen it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an app that does exactly what you asked for: [Stay by Cordless Dog](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/).

> If you're fastidious about keeping your windows tidy, Stay is for you. Stay ensures that your windows are always where you want them to be, even as you connect and disconnect displays.

Answer (score 1):

Safari can save all open tabs from a single window & reopen them with one click. Bookmarks Menu->'Add Bookmarks for these n Tabs'.

Not certain for other apps, though as a workaround you could save copies of open documents all to the same project folder & reopen from there.

Answer (score 1):

For windows placement, [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) will do what you're asking for (and more besides):

> After laying out your windows as you wish, create a new Arrange Windows Custom Control, and click the Save Snapshot button. This will save the layout—size and location—of all opened windows (optionally not saving obscured windows). Later, when you want your custom arrangement back, type the keyboard shortcut, or activate the saved layout via Moom's menus.

It offers a free trial period, so you can see if it suits your needs.